# Can a url obtain the resource or information on the resource, a report, or resource itself?

Tags: html, jquery

I go out on the limb and try things. I packed documents in a url can i didgetly sign it.

A report I received, but instead embedded in a URL. I was thinking can I use the developer tools and check the URL now? why can't software be held right in the URL?

Comment: Urls have limited length. What kind of information do want to query/offer?

Comment: Would [OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) be an option?

Comment: umm, what do you meant by "embedded in the url?" also, is that "didgetly" or "digitally?"

Comment: @BagusTesa I think OP wants to `encodeURIComponent` an entire *software*, script - into the URI. Not sure how it this improbable task (due to chars length) related to digitally signing a software though.